# Rewrite URL Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

i'm using Codeigniter for my web app, i changed the structure of the project as the following :

```
my_Project
          --- application
          --- public_html
                         --- resources
          --- system
```

I created the folder public_html to seperate my public files from the classes .. etc, but now i have to call this url every time :

```
my_project/public_html/controller/action
```

i want it to be this way :

```
my_project/controller/action
```

I already moved out the index.php from the URL using the rewrite mode, but i can't seem to remove the public_html as well :

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
# you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
# If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
# let it as it is
RewriteBase /uca-flsh/public_html

# Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|images|resources|public_html)

# No rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

.config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/uca-flsh/public_html';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /my_project/public_html/controller/action  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ my_project/controller/action [L,R]
```

Comment: I added those lines at the end of my .htaccess, still didn't work

Comment: They need to go to the top of your `.htaccess` under `RewriteEngine On`. Also, clear your cache before testing it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, still nothing :s